# Errors being created by admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, ajax, plugin-ninja-forms

I'm building a site in Wordpress and using the Ninja Forms plugin.

While developing locally everything worked perfectly but now I've installed on my server When trying to submit a form I'm getting the following error and the form just stalls:

`"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://319433-1.temp-dns.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
admin-ajax.php
ERRORS: Internal Server Error
front-end.js (line 2)
Object { readyState=4,  status=500,  statusText="Internal Server Error",  more...}
front-end.js (line 2)
Parse Error`

I have turned on DEBUG mode in Wordpress but that gave no clues.

Any ideas on what could be going on?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deactivating plugins one by one and you'll findout which plugin is conflicting with your ajax call. Then we can debug error easily .

But I am sure this is because of plugin conflict You just need to check which one is it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Umer, it was indeed the 'WP HTML Mail' plugin that was causing the issue. I've contacted the plugin author to see if we can resolve the issue as it's designed to work with Ninja Forms. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect! you can upvote my answer then :)

Comment: I did try but as I'm new to the Wordpress part of Stack Exchange and have less than 15 reputation it doesn't show publicly, sorry